# How to determine and return letter in array that comes first in the alphabet

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans

Write a program that includes a class named Letters.

Class: The class should contain the following:

```
 Field:
```

Array of 6 characters (chars)
      Methods:

- No-arg constructor that prompts the user for the 6 characters to be
  stored in the array.
- Prints elements of the array Determine and    return letter in array
  that comes first in the alphabet

  - Determine and    return letter that comes last in the alphabet
- Method to change an element of the array. The method should contain
  two arguments. One argument should contain an integer that represents
  the index of the element to be changed. The second argument should
  contain the new value to be stored in the array location.

Main part of program: The main part of the program should contain the following:

- Create Letters object
- Print the elements
- Print the letter that comes first in the alphabet that is stored in
  the array.
- Print the letter that comes last in the alphabet that is stored in
  the array Change the last element of the array to ‘z’
- Print the elements again

```
    char[] letter = new char[6];

    private char Letters(){
      for( int x = 0;  x< letter.length; x++)
      {
          System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
          String str = keyboard.nextLine();
          letter[x] = str.charAt(0);
      }  
      System.out.println(letter);
      return 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: If this is an assignment, can you provide the exact assignment text? It looks like you have more fundamental problems than just the alphabetical order of characters, but your question is a bit too vague for me to be able to provide useful assistance.

Comment: I have provided the exact assignment text up above

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.sort(letter)`. That sorts the array alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Streams` API like this:

```
final char[] letters = "StackOverflow".toCharArray();
final char   maxChar = (char) new String(letters).chars().max().getAsInt();
```